# SSH connection asks for password connecting to Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, containers

I've already looked for similar questions and tried changing several things in my configuration but couldn't come up with a solution.

I'm trying to connecting via SSH to a Docker container, here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get install -y openssh-server

RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo "remote_user:test1234" | chpasswd && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh -p && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    mkdir -p -m0755 /var/run/sshd


COPY id_rsa.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user   -R /home/remote_user && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN apt-get install -y php php-mbstring php-xml php-bcmath php-fpm && \
    apt-get install -y composer && apt-get install -y vim
    
RUN apt-get install -y nginx

CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Once I try to connect to the container as "remote_user" with `ssh -Tv remote_user@staging.local` (where "staging.local" is the container IP) I get this message:

```
...
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:5QNPe89pdQp+tgE61N9YPaIJEs8QR9DxaChmStfvzBU agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: xxx@xxx RSA SHA256:C+VWlGUd4mVywHnh8JWtjL0gmO8cuqUEs4YYCbQGvaE agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
remote_user@staging.local's password:
```

As you can see it can't connect and is asking for the password.

If I `ls -ll` .ssh folder files in my host machine I have this:

```
-rw------- 1 xxx xxx 2610 Jan  3 12:08 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx  577 Jan  3 12:08 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx  222 Jan  3 12:25 known_hosts
```

If I `docker exec` into the container as root user and see permissions of `/home/remote_user/.ssh` I have:

- **home** folder permissions:
  `drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan  3 11:22 home`
- **remote_user** folder permissions:
  `drwxr-xr-x 1 remote_user remote_user 4096 Jan  3 11:22 remote_user`
- **.ssh** folder permissions:
  `drwx------ 1 remote_user remote_user 4096 Jan  3 11:22 .ssh`
- **authorized_keys** file permissions:
  `-rw------- 1 remote_user remote_user 577 Jan  3 11:08 authorized_keys`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you forward the port :

```
docker run -p 222:22 your-image
```

then :

```
ssh -p 222 remote_user@localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the permissions for the `/home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys` to 400 instead of 600. Other than that, I don't see any difference between my own setup.

p.s.
My setup runs with ubuntu 18.04 so maybe they changed something since then.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it still gives the same error